# Adding 401 custom error to system.webServer.httpErrors gives "Unable to start debugging on the web server" error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, visual-studio-debugging, http-error

I started with a blank MVC 3 web application. I created a new website in my local IIS for localhost:80 and configured my new MVC 3 project to use that web server instead of the VS development web server. At this point I can run and debug the project as normal. But if I add this to my web.config, I get an "Unable to start debugging on the web server" error. I can select Start without debugging and it works fine. What's the deal?

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="401"/>
        <error statusCode="401" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error401" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

`httpErrors` are the new element which is only used by IIS7.  This seems a little weird, however try adding the following in web config under `system.web section`:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"  defaultRedirect="~/error">
    <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error401" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: I'm using IIS7. also, I am looking to use the `existingResponse="Replace"` feature, whereas system.web.customErrors can only redirect AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could give some more hope here, but after extensive internet research, it seems that there is no resolution. Whenever this config node is enabled, debugging will not start, even if there are no obvious errors outside of debugging.

I have previously noticed that issues with the certificate can cause a similar error to occur. Apparently the debugger is not seeing something it expects and is failing as a result.

My solution will be to only enable this directive for our testing environment and above while leaving it disabled for development.